# Calling other functions inside Lambda [C++/CX]

Tags: asynchronous, windows-8, windows-store-apps, c++-cx

I'm working on a Windows Store app (C++). The app loads data from database using a webservice and I want that data to be shown on the page.
Why can I not call functions w.r.t an instance of a class created inside the enclosing function? Here's the LoadState event of my app's first page...

```
void ItemsPage::LoadState(Object^ navigationParameter, IMap<String^, Object^>^ pageState)
{
    (void) pageState;
    StorySource^ storysource = ref new StorySource();

    task<wstring> (GetFromDB(cancellationTokenSource.get_token()))
.then([this, storysource](task<wstring> response){
            try
            {
                auto resp = response.get();
                storysource->Init(resp);
                DefaultViewModel->Insert("Items", storysource->AllGroups);
             }
             catch(COMException^ ex)
             {  ...  }
        });
}
```

I can't execute any function inside the .then() block. I need to somehow chain the completion of GetFromDB() to StorySource::Init() and this to DefaultViewModel->Insert().

I am very new to asynchronous programming. Please explain me what I am doing wrong and what could be the solution to my problem. Thanks in advance.

Comment: One recommendation: pass the result of the async task into the lambda instead of the task and use a separate error handler closure in the continuation instead of `try { auto resp = task.get() } catch...`
Apart from that, an error code or other description of the error you get would be helpful.

Comment: Thanks for the help... it is working now after adding 'task_continuation_context::use_current()' at the end of the then() block.